# Deploying a Django App

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I'm very sorry for such a simple question-- I'm new at WSGI development, and I'm grateful for any patience you can afford.

I made a Django app; it works great in development mode. I run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and then direct my browser to `127.0.0.1:8000`, and voila, there is my app.

From here I *absolutely cannot* figure out how to run my app in production mode. I've read several pages [like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/) [and this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/) and several others on StackOverflow. But I have no idea of where to even direct my browser to see if my page is working.

I've installed `apache2`, `mod_python`, etc., but I think the problem is that my misunderstanding is at such a more basic level. When I've done CGI programs in the past, I direct my browser to `webroot/file.html` with a form that calls `cgi-bin/file.cgi`, which generates html output. I don't know if I am supposed to navigate to a `.wsgi` page, etc.

Under the assumption that I'm supposed to navigate to a `.wsgi file`, I've also tried making   a file containing:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

path = '/home/orserang/nonparametric-protein/src/www/mysite$'
if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)
```

and added

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

to my `apache2/httpd.conf` file, so that its contents are:

```
<Location "/mysite/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
    PythonOption django.root /mysite
    PythonDebug On
    PythonPath "['/home/orserang/nonparametric-protein/src/www/mysite'] + ['/home/orserang/nonparametric-protein/src/'] + sys.path"
    WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /home/orserang/nonparametric-protein/src/www/mysite/django.wsgi
</Location>
```

But when I restart `apache`, it says:

**Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

WSGIScriptAlias not allowed here**

Given that I don't even know *where* I should point my browser to get to a Django `wsgi` page, I figured there is something easy that I'm doing quite wrong.

Perhaps Django WSGI apps require something to run in the background, which will listen for requests (rather than go through `apache`)?

The online Django documentation on views and databases alone are substantial compared to the documentation for deployment; therefore, my best guess is that this is such a simple thing to do.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: deploying to a live server is no easy task (depending on your server), but it is unclear to me what you're asking.  Are you looking for a step by step guide to deployment, or is there a specific area where you're getting hung up?

Comment: @DanielNill I fleshed out the question a bit more; I don't even know where to point my browser in the end (my Django project has no single file that launches the others as a `cgi` would). And when I tried to make a `.wsgi` file as directed by the documentation, `apache` failed to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django Book 2.0 has an overview about this. It's not typically linked to in the Django docs:

[Chapter 12: Deploying Django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/)

Look at the "Using Django with Apache and mod_python" section.

Comment: I made a lot of mistakes-- but I think the biggest was not actually CREATING a Django app of that name on the server (I thought it would work as long as it had some string pointing to the correct place, but I believe there is some registry that needs to know where the Django apps live). Thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up mod_python and mod_wsgi deployment methods. Get rid of everything inside the `Location` directive except for the `WSGIScriptAlias` line.

Comment: Add get rid of the Location directive as well. WSGIScriptAlias should not be inside of Location or Directory directives. They should just have the WSGIScriptAlias line by itself out of what they have.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote shell script that deploys a django project on apache for linux,

https://github.com/mukulu/shell-scripts/blob/master/deploy-django.sh

You only need to configure couple of variables in first lines of the code,
and it'll figure out the rest.

It pretty much checks and install dependencies for django, writes apache configurations that deploys your project and restart the server.

I'm planning to re-write it in python(I wrote it in a hurry)
Feel free to re-use.

Variables are:

```
SITE_PREFIX="/djangoproject"

MEDIA_URL="/media"

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX="/static/admin/"

MEDIA_ROOT=""

DJANGO_VERSION="1.3.1"

APACHE2_CONFIG="/etc/apache2/conf.d"     #Apache configurations directory in yoru system.
```

Comment: +1 That sounds great. Maybe that would be good for a community wiki?

Answer (score 0):

This might be not for a novice, but you can take a look - http://packages.python.org/django-fab-deploy/

It's the library for automating the deploying process. It supports servers based primarily on Debian Lenny or Squeeze.